# copy file with cat in execl() finction

Tags: cat

how can I copy a file with full path and rename it in C program using execl? 
can I use this instruction:

```
execl("/bin/cat","cat",path_source,">",path_destination,NULL);
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted looks like it's intended to mimic the following
shell command:

```
cat path_source >path_destination
```

But, in that scenario, `>` isn't a parameter to `cat`; instead, it's
interpreted by your shell, which will run `cat` with a single
parameter `path_source`, and its standard output connected to
`path_destination`. (So your C code really does
`cat path_source '>' path_destination`.)

One way to imitate what the `cat` command above does is to construct a
string containing your shell command (`"cat ... >..."`), and then pass
that, using exec, as an argument to `/bin/sh -c`, but it's hard to
make it reliable and safe if you don't know for sure that the file
names verify some constraints.

If you are going to simply rename a file, it might be best to use
standard function `rename` from `stdio.h` instead. If not, please
clarify your question.

Comment: the probleme is that i renamed my file in a gtk message box and return it into a string variable then concatenate it with the destination folder, i tried with cp command but it doesn't work, can I do that: execl("/bin/cat","command",NULL); and i put all the concatenated command i string variable "command"???

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the call to `cp` you tried, and the error messages you got, if any.

Comment: i posted my problem with cp in here : http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/245023/cp-with-full-renamed-path-in-execl-c-program?noredirect=1#comment421237_245023

Comment: I posted an answer your other question.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a homework assignment, so I'm being intentionally vague.

It sounds like the requirement is to mimic the behavior of the shell when using the output redirection operator.  You'd need to manipulate the standard file descriptors before calling `execl()` such that standard output of the calling process was an open file descriptor for the target output file.  That way when cat writes to standard output, the content will go to the target file.